# "По средам", ударение

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Какое из этих ударений нормативное: "по срЕдам" или "по средАм" (Имеется в виду день недели)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется в виду день недели, то орфоэпическая норма - *по средАм* (Словарь "Русское словесное ударение").

Comment: Вот только много ли людей будет так говорить? :((

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно: если имеется в виду день недели, то орфоэпическая норма - по средАм.